# How to make a photo gallery like application with jquery mobile using highcharts instead of images?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, highcharts

Hi guys Im working on a mobile web site using jquery mobile, saw many examples of photo gallery integration with jquery mobile tried most of them and they work out just fine.  My problem is instead of images I need to use highcharts inside the gallery.  Is there any plugins for this or is this even possible with jquery mobile?

Thanks in advance guys!

Note: I wont be converting the mobile web site into a native app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that highchart needs is a div/element for itself to render to. You should in theory be able to do it into any photo gallery. One thing you should make note of is, high chart is dependent on the DOM and hence can only be added after the gallery is loaded to the DOM.